# remove/hide card.io/paypal logo android

Tags: android, paypal, card.io

I am integrating Card.io in my android app and I want to remove the paypal logo. 
I searched stackoverflow and got to know the usage of EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO.

Setting this to true or false, shows either Paypal or Card.io logo. 
My client requires that there should be no logo at all.
Any help?

Answer (score 13):

Update on this answer - as of 4.0+, card.io now supports full removal of the card.io logo with [EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO](http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CardIOActivity.html#EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO).

Answer (score 2):

Josh from card.io here. There is no way to entirely disable logos.

Comment: Can we make changes to the layout color etc?

Comment: I have tried CardIOActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE but I have to change the background color of header which has text Card Details. I also need to change the color of Done and Cancel button. I already checked documentation but could not proceed.

Comment: no, we can.
we just need to add 
intent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true);

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Brateman's answer above is partly correct. The PayPal logo is actually shown in 2 places, the card scanning view and the card details entry view. In order to hide both of them you need to add two putExtras to your scan intent:

```
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON, false);
```