# How to completely remove/hide card.io/paypal logo in iOS

Tags: ios, card.io

I am using card io for scanning card in iOS app

While scanning is there any way to hide paypal/cardio logo image, please guide

Comment: Hi, Initially I was getting paypal logo. After scanViewController.useCardIOLogo = YES; I am getting card io logo. Don't know how to hide logo image

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113240/remove-hide-card-io-paypal-logo-android

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for reply. I have read that story.. so final conclusion is there is no way to hide logos? Pls confirm

Answer (score 14):

Update on this answer - as of 4.0+, card.io now supports full removal of the card.io logo with the `hideCardIOLogo` property in `CardIOView` and `CardIOPaymentViewController`.

Answer (score 7):

```
CardIOPaymentViewController *scanViewController = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPaymentDelegate:self];
scanViewController.hideCardIOLogo=YES;
```

Comment: What file do I have to change?

Comment: this is objective c Code , "hideCardIOLogo" is property of CardIOPaymentViewController.   for ionic you can chcek https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/card-io/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Card.IO logo or the PayPal logo but cannot remove them completely.