# Using card.io can we remove pay pal logo in card details screen after scanning card number or customise the UI

Tags: android, scanning, card.io

Is it possible to remove paypal logo from card details screen after card is being scanned by card.io. 
Paypal logo in card details screen not in card scanning screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove/hide card.io/paypal logo android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113240/remove-hide-card-io-paypal-logo-android)

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?  I'm not aware of a PayPal logo on the card details screen.